# Can beautiful soup also hit webpage events?

Tags: selenium, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, selenium-webdriver

Beautiful Soup is a Python library for pulling data out of HTML and XML files. I will use it to extract webpage data,but i didn't find out any way to click the buttons,`anchor label` which are used in my case the page navigation. So for this shall I have to use any other or  `beautiful soup` has the capability i didn't aware of.

Please advice me!

Comment: Can I use `selenium and beautiful soup` together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your tags/comment, yes, you can use them together (Selenium and BeautifulSoup), and no, you can't directly use BeautifulSoup to execute events (clicking etc.). Although I haven't ever used them together in the same situation, a hypothetical situation could involve using Selenium to navigate to a target page via a certain path (i.e. `click()` these options and then `click()` the button to the next page), and then using BeautifulSoup to read the `driver.page_source` (where `driver` is the Selenium driver you created to 'drive' the browser). Since `driver.page_source` is the HTML of the page, you can use BeautifulSoup as you are used to, parsing out whatever information you need.

Simple example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

# Create your driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Get a page
driver.get('http://news.ycombinator.com')

# Feed the source to BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)

print(soup.title)   # <title>Hacker News</title>
```

The main idea is that anytime you need to read the source of a page, you can pass `driver.page_source` to `BeautifulSoup` in order to read whatever you want.

Comment: thanks for your response! Now I would like to know how would i embedded such modules one for web page navigation using `selenium webdriver` and other for webpage scrapping using `beautiful soup`? how those two different `.py` file would communicate between them. A bit confused here I am. Guide me here to understand. You can take [ADO](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/ado/8530.asp) as an example to go to next page or scrapping the values to a textfile which are under the `Properties` section. Guide me here with a demo if possible for you please.

Comment: @CodeLover Sure, editing with a very simple example. Hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks for showing your interest to help me. A knowledgeable person should be like you! :)

Comment: @CodeLover Ha no problem at all, hope it gets you on the right track - good luck!