# scraping a website that requires you to scroll down

Tags: javascript, python, dynamic, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this website here:

However, it requires that I scroll down in order to collect additional data. I have no idea how to scroll down using Beautiful soup or python. Does anybody here know how?

The code is a bit of a mess but here it is.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from testtest.items import TesttestItem
import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
import re
import time

class MLStripper(HTMLParser):


class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "A1Locker"

        def strip_tags(html):
            s = MLStripper()
            s.feed(html)
            return s.get_data()

     allowed_domains = ['https://www.a1lockerrental.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.a1lockerrental.com/self-storage/mo/st-
 louis/4427-meramec-bottom-rd-facility/unit-sizes-prices#/units?
 category=all']

     def parse(self, response):

                 url='http://www.a1lockerrental.com/self-storage/mo/st-
louis/4427-meramec-bottom-rd-facility/unit-sizes-prices#/units?
category=Small'
                driver = webdriver.Firefox()
                driver.get(url)
                html = driver.page_source
                soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        url2='http://www.a1lockerrental.com/self-storage/mo/st-louis/4427-
meramec-bottom-rd-facility/unit-sizes-prices#/units?category=Medium'
        driver2 = webdriver.Firefox()
                driver2.get(url2)
                html2 = driver.page_source
                soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html2, 'html.parser')                
                #soup.append(soup2)
                #print soup
        items = []
        inside = "Indoor"
                outside = "Outdoor"
        inside_units = ["5 x 5", "5 x 10"]
        outside_units = ["10 x 15","5 x 15", "8 x 10","10 x 10","10 x 
20","10 x 25","10 x 30"]
        sizeTagz = soup.findAll('span',{"class":"sss-unit-size"})
        sizeTagz2 = soup2.findAll('span',{"class":"sss-unit-size"})
        #print soup.findAll('span',{"class":"sss-unit-size"})



        rateTagz = soup.findAll('p',{"class":"unit-special-offer"})


        specialTagz = soup.findAll('span',{"class":"unit-special-offer"})
        typesTagz = soup.findAll('div',{"class":"unit-info"},)

        rateTagz2 = soup2.findAll('p',{"class":"unit-special-offer"})


        specialTagz2 = soup2.findAll('span',{"class":"unit-special-offer"})
        typesTagz2 = soup2.findAll('div',{"class":"unit-info"},)
        yield {'date': datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%y"),
                'name': "A1Locker"
                   }
        size = []
        for n in range(len(sizeTagz)):
                    print len(rateTagz)
                    print len(typesTagz)

                    if "Outside" in (typesTagz[n]).get_text():



                            size.append(re.findall(r'\d+',
 (sizeTagz[n]).get_text()))
                            size.append(re.findall(r'\d+',
 (sizeTagz2[n]).get_text()))
                            print "logic hit"
                for i in range(len(size)):
                        yield {
                    #soup.findAll('p',{"class":"icon-bg"})
                    #'name': soup.find('strong', {'class':'high'}).text

                    'size': size[i]
                    #"special": (specialTagz[n]).get_text(),
                    #"rate": re.findall(r'\d+',(rateTagz[n]).get_text()),
                    #"size": i.css(".sss-unit-size::text").extract(),
                    #"types": "Outside"

    }
            driver.close()
```

The desired output of the code is to have it display the data collected from this webpage: http://www.a1lockerrental.com/self-storage/mo/st-louis/4427-meramec-bottom-rd-facility/unit-sizes-prices#/units?category=all

To do so would require being able to scroll down to view the rest of the data. At least that is how it would be done in my mind.

Thanks,
DM123

Comment: what have you tried? what's the current output and what is the desired output?

Comment: You need to provide the code you have tried, what it does do and output, and what it fails to ouptput, in addition I am unable to see a link to a website

Comment: ok give me a second i will add the code

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147441/can-beautiful-soup-also-hit-webpage-events

Comment: driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);") I managed to get it working with this code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a webdriver function that provides this capability. BeautifulSoup doesn't do anything besides parse the site.

Check this out: http://webdriver.io/api/utility/scroll.html

Comment: driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")  I have tried using this javascript line in python but nothing happens even when I include it in a loop. I guess I need to do more research

Comment: I get the folllowing error when running that line of code:  DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:53730/session/938b7cdf-917e-4c7a-84ef-eb38aaa38cd6/execute/sync {"sessionId": "938b7cdf-917e-4c7a-84ef-eb38aaa38cd6", "args": [], "script": "return document.body.scrollHeight"}

Answer (score 4):

The website you're trying to scrape is loading content dynamically using JavaScript. Unfortunately, many web scrapers, such as beautiful soup, cannot execute JavaScript on their own. There are a number of options, however, many in the form of headless browsers. A classic one is [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org), but it may be worth taking a look at this [great list of options on GitHub](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers), some of which may play nicely with beautiful soup, such as Selenium.

Keeping Selenium in mind, the answer to [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14147441/can-beautiful-soup-also-hit-webpage-events) may also help.